# Remove SVN repository refrences in XCode5

Tags: ios, xcode, svn-repository

I am facing some issues while importing files to my project. When I import these files which are already linked to another repository it contains the references of old repository and I am unable to Commit/Add these files to new repository. I tried other solution like searching for .svn files in the folder and deleting them and also through command line tool but i am not able to remove the references of old repository.

Please suggest some solution for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can check out this answer in superuser, from my personal experience this is the only way of doing it. Here is the link to the answer:
https://superuser.com/questions/388020/how-to-use-terminal-to-delete-all-svn-folders-recursively

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I know is to delete all .svn files from ALL sub-directories. Maybe you can create/find a script for doing this job.
In any case, if there is a better way to import the project linked to another repository, I would be happy know as well.

Comment: What if you don't see the .svn files in the respective folder?

Comment: @iphonedev23, if you will copy the project to Microsoft Operating System, you will see all hidden folders. Another way is to create a script for deleting all .SVN files.